# If I already have Cloud Functions Admin role, why do I need Cloud Functions Invoker role to run cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I have been assigned Cloud Functions Admin role in the IAM permissions settings. I have created a cloud function callable by HTTP. When I make the request it throws

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /<function name> from this server.
```

Apparently I have to add the Cloud Functions Invoker role to be able to call cloud functions, but this seems unnecessary since I'm already a Cloud Functions Admin, whose permissions surely encompass any held within Cloud Functions Invoker.

Is this strange behavior correct or have I taken a wrong turn?

---

I have now added `Owner` role aswell as `Cloud Functions Admin` and it still throws the same 403.

I have updated my CLI using `npm install -g firebase-tools` - now on `v11.8.0`.

I have added `allUsers` principal to have `Cloud Functions Invoker`.

I have checked any errors logged in the console and `gcf-artifacts has failed as the Artifact Registry API is not active. Please enable the API and try again.` - however when I check if the Artifact Registry API is enabled, it is.

I am now attempting to enable unauthenticated HTTP function invocation using [this article](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam) however I can't find the **Configuration** panel within the google cloud console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing the same issue and have already completed all of my troubleshooting above, delete your cloud function and redeploy it.

It's that simple.